# Comparator problems with output

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, pwm, comparator

I am kinda new to electronics design and I am having some trouble with the [Analog Devices LT319AN](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/119a319afc.pdf) chip. I am trying to do simple 250KHz PWM which worked on a lesser LM393 chip in this exact setup. I know I am probably missing something simple due to the lack of some basic knowledge, any help would be much appreciated! Anyway I have added a schematic diagram and oscilloscope pictures so you can see what I am dealing with.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:

Forgot the Schematic!

[image]

Edit #2:

Thank you @DKNguyen! Per your input I added 10k OHM resistors between +5vDC and ground to bias the input's and this is the output am now getting:

https://youtu.be/hdRFULSaPc0

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ceramic decoupling capacitors across the power pins of the comparator.

Input bias currents need a DC path to flow. You can't just leave them DC floating like that.

You can normally handle this by sticking resistors from each input to gnd. But in your case, you should stick each input in the middle of a resistor divider instead to DC bias in the middle of the input common mode range the because your input is bipolar but the comparator is not (it only has a unipolar supply). But this should have been an issue with the LM393 too.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foxi9N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to DC Bias the input with my frequency generator and just add the resistor to ground for testing? And do I do the same with my ramp input? Would this work for testing so I can use my frequency generator to bias the ac input in the middle of the ramp signal?

Comment: @Boeggs Not as long as you have those DC block caps. They block DC after all, including from your frequency generator.

Comment: Ah that was a lightbulb xD I forgot DC can't pass through a capacitor like that.

Comment: Thank's buddy I added a video of what the output looks like now. Thank you for the awesome explanation!

Comment: @Boeggs Note your comparator does not have rail to rail input. I don't think you have enough input range with your large input amplitude and low voltage supply so that can just bias it lower than 50% to avoid clipping. You're input signal is getting clipped from the comparator's perspective.

Comment: I will be putting a line input from an audio source into the input eventually through a 10k resistor. Will this be enough to stop clipping? Also I am new so I apologize for the question but so long as the input from the audio source does not peak over the ramp wake p-p voltage it wont clip correct? or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Boeggs Short story: your comparator can only measure voltages between 1 and 3V when running off 5V. It is blind beyond that which may or may not be a problem for you. It is on the datasheet under input voltage range. So biasing it at 50% is best since it is symetrically limited on high and low end. (I thought it could measure all the way to GND, but guess not).

Comment: Ah I understand now sorry for being slow! I will keep that in mind and bias the input's to 2 volts then. (Which will work perfectly for a small P-P triangle waveform to compensate for the 10k input resistance.)

Also, am I thinking about this correctly? It might be another question (I am sorry if I am spamming questions...) but I have in in my head that the ramp amplitude in correlation to the audio input (after input resistance and dc biasing) will control the gain? 0db Gain = Ramp wave that makes the output voltage exactly the same as the input audio voltage Such 2Vpp -> 2Vpp?

Comment: @Boeggs I don't know because I haven't thought it through but that doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: Okay no problem, more to learn on my end! Anyway thanks for all the help!!